# Вышивать на машинке

Tags: лексика

Вдумался в выражение "вышивать на машинке". Вышивать можно на ткани, на коже или еще на какой-то поверхности. Но не на машинку же наносится вышивка. Вышивают с помощью машинки или машинкой. Правильно ли тогда говорить "вышивать на машинке"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно. Одно из значений предлога "НА" (в сочетании с предложным падежом) - делать с помощью чего-либо. *Вышивать на машинке, жарить на масле.*

Answer (score 3):

Если, например, речь идет об обработке дерева, мы говорим: **выточить, вырезать на станке**. Это ведь не значит 'выточить, вырезать на поверхности станка'. Всем понятно, что имеется в виду 'выточить с помощью станка'. Выражение **вышивать на пяльцах** означает 'вышивать с помощью пялец'. **Вышивать на руках** означает 'вышивать с помощью рук, руками'. Предлог НА в русском языке многозначный, хоть и не является самостоятельной частью речи. В одном из значений данный предлог 'указывает на средство, способ, характер осуществления чего-л.' (ср.: *аккомпанировать себе на гитаре*). Поэтому выражение **вышивать на машинке** абсолютно правильное.

Answer (score 0):

"Вышивать на машинке" - вполне литературно. К своему стыду, я плохо представляю сам процесс, но, похоже, здесь прямая аналогия с "играть на пианино" или "варить на плите".

Comment: Да обычный процесс: пяльцы с тканью вставляются в швейную машинку, отключается механизм протяжки ткани - и вперед, к [творчеству](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs3waAvqcgQ)  
Кстати, видео занятное!

Comment: Чтоб я ещё знал, где у меня пяльцы и куда ткань протягивают ))))

Comment: Ну, судя по видео в ссылке, пяльцы необязательны. У Вас и так много талантов, так что вышивать можете вручную ))))